# Sum of TOP 5 PERCENT and sum of all as two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `All_Sources` with the following columns:

`svcmonth`
`source`
`member`
`cost`

I'm trying to write a query that will return the sum of the costs of the `TOP 5 PERCENT` of members as the first column, and the sum of the costs of all members in the table as the second column.  I'm able to get these two numbers individually with the following two queries:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.fivepercentcost)
FROM
(SELECT
TOP 5 PERCENT member, 
SUM(cost) AS fivepercentcost
FROM dbo.All_Sources
WHERE svcmonth = '2013, 01' AND source = 'HC'
GROUP BY member
ORDER BY SUM(cost) DESC) t1
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(cost) AS 
FROM dbo.All_Sources
WHERE svcmonth = '2013, 01' AND source = 'HC'
```

However, where I'm stuck is trying to put these two queries together so that the two results will display side by side in two columns.  I've been trying to work with CTEs and the `OVER()` function without any luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Sample Data**

```
svcmonth   source   member   cost
2012, 12   HC       1        50
2012, 12   BA       1        40
2013, 01   HC       1        55
2013, 01   HC       2        100
2013, 01   BA       1        50
2013, 02   BA       2        45
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to work with?  I am vague on a few things.

Comment: See edit above.  Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Let me know if my answer gets you the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there.  The trick would be to do an `OVER` and `PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)` so that you can do in inline `SUM` of the table.

```
SELECT  SUM(fivepercentcost) AS fivepercentcost, 
        Total
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT 
            member,
            SUM(cost) AS fivepercentcost,
            Total
    FROM (
        SELECT  member,
                cost, 
                SUM(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Total     
        FROM    dbo.All_Sources
        WHERE   svcmonth = '2013, 01' 
            AND source = 'HC'
    ) A
    GROUP BY member, Total
    ORDER BY SUM(cost) DESC
) A
GROUP BY Total
```

Comment: Thanks--works like a charm. Could you explain the `PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)` part?

Comment: Great!  You can look at it like an in-line `GROUP BY`. Since we didn't want to group on anything, I cheated using `SELECT NULL`.  Please don't forget to upvote the answers that helped you as well!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare two variables, load them individually and select them both as follows:

```
DECLARE @TOP5 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @ALL AS FLOAT

SELECT @TOP5 = SUM(t1.fivepercentcost)
FROM
(SELECT
TOP 5 PERCENT member, 
SUM(cost) AS fivepercentcost
FROM dbo.All_Sources
WHERE svcmonth = '2013, 01' AND source = 'HC'
GROUP BY member
ORDER BY SUM(cost) DESC) t1

SELECT @ALL = SUM(cost) AS 
FROM dbo.All_Sources
WHERE svcmonth = '2013, 01' AND source = 'HC'

SELECT @TOP5, @ALL
```